# Column 'title' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, blogs

I have a website where people can insert there own blog.
But when you press the button send to make there own blog there come's an error

Column 'AccountID' cannot be null.

The new blog I tried to make also doesn't appear in my phpmyadmin.

This is my php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once ("includes/dbconnect.inc.php");
    require_once ("includes/functions.inc.php");
    $BlogID = "";
    $BlogTitel = "";
    $Tekst = "";
    $AccountID = "";


/* Een bestaand blog aanpassen */
    if (isset($_GET["bid"])) {
        $BlogID = $_GET["bid"];
        //query 1 bepaalde blog opvragen
        //vraagteken wordt door een waarde vervangen binnen de if
        $qrySelectBlog = 
            "SELECT BlogTitel, Tekst
                FROM tblBlog
                WHERE BlogID = ?";
        //query voorbereiden : kijken of die correct is     
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbconnect, $qrySelectBlog)) {
            //variabele verbinden aan de parameters (de vraagtekens)
            //door het type van de variabele mee te geven, zit er extra beveiliging ingebouwd
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $BlogID);
            //query uitvoeren
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            //waarden koppelen aan variabelen
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $BlogTitel, $Tekst);
            //waarden van 1 record in de variabelen stoppen
            //mogelijk omdat je zeker bent dat je gegevens hebt van slechts 1 record
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
            //resultset sluiten
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") { //formulier is verzonden
        $BlogID = $_POST["BlogID"];
        $BlogTitel = $_POST["BlogTitel"];
        $Tekst = $_POST["Tekst"];
        $AccountID = $_POST["AccountID"];
        //controleren op verplichte velden
        if (!empty($BlogTitel) && !empty($Tekst)) {
            if(!isset($fout)) {
                //alles in orde, verder met verwerking
                //tekst voorbereiden om toe te voegen aan de DB
                $BlogTitel = prepText($BlogTitel);  
                $Tekst = prepText($Tekst);
                //controleren of het om een bestaand blog gaat
                if($BlogID == ""){
                    //nieuwe Blog
                    $qryInsertBlog = 
                    "INSERT INTO tblBlog (AccountID, BlogID, BlogTitel, Tekst)
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbconnect, $qryInsertBlog)) {
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiss", $AccountID, $BlogID, $BlogTitel, $Tekst);
                        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                            //query succesvol uitgevoerd    
                            $feedback = "<p>Toevoegen van jouw blog was succesvol</p>";
                        } else {
                            //query niet succesvol uitgevoerd   
                            $fout = "<p>Het toevoegen van de blog is mislukt</p>";
                            $fout .= mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
                        }
                    } //if($stmt 
                } else { //if($blogID
                    //bestaand Blog
                    $qryUpdateBlog = 
                        "UPDATE tblBlog
                            SET BlogTitel = ?, Tekst = ?,
                            WHERE BlogID = ?";
                    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbconnect, $qryUpdateBlog)) {
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $BlogTitel, $Tekst, $BlogID);
                        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                            //query succesvol uitgevoerd    
                            $feedback = "<p>Aanpassen van de blog was succesvol</p>";
                        } else {
                            //query niet succesvol uitgevoerd   
                            $fout = "<p>Het aanpassen van de blog is mislukt</p>";
                            $fout .= mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
                        }
                    } //if($stmt 

                }
            } //if(!isset($fout)) 
        } else { //if (!empty($BlogTitel)
            //niet alle verplichte velden zijn ingevuld
            $fout = "<p>U hebt niet alle verplichte velden ingevuld</p>";   
        } //if (!empty($BlogTitel)
    } //if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Toevoegen Blog</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
</head>

<body>
<form id="addBlog" name="addBlog" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
    <?php
        if(isset($fout)) {
            echo $fout; 
        } elseif(isset($feedback)) {
            echo $feedback; 
        }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="BlogID" value="<?php echo $BlogID;?>">
    <label for="BlogTitel">Blog Naam</label>
    <input type="text" id="naam" name="BlogTitel" placeholder="Blog Titel" required value="<?php echo $BlogTitel;?>">
    <label for="Tekst">Tekst</label>
    <textarea name="Tekst" id="Tekst" placeholder="De tekst voor jouw blog" required><?php echo $Tekst;?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: typo here `$POST["AccountID"];` it would be `$_POST["AccountID"];`

Comment: I just did that. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is beacause you are posting $_POST['AccountID'] as null and in your database it is not allowed to save null values.

set $_POST['AccountID'] to some value or allow null for this field in your database.